# Loading model prints query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to setup a codeigniter-page which already works perfect on another sever.
I have changed the database.php file such that it connects to the local database instead. Else, nothing else is changed.

But when i load the page it just print out the queries from my model.

[image]

I believed I'm well connected to the database I experience other errors if there is no connection to the DB.
I believe it is a configuration error as nothing else is changed on the page (and it is working fine on another server).

There is used CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Does any know this error?

UPDATE: Here is snips of my controller (I call index-page). The inherited class (MY_Controller) is empty

```
class Page extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()   {
    //  session_start();
       parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Page_model');
}

public function index() {
//  $this->show(1);
}
```

And the page_model which i load:

```
<?

class Page_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_page($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id); 
$query = $this->db->get('gahk_page');
return $query->result();
}

function update_by_id($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('gahk_page', $data); 
}

}

?>
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: In order for us to help you, please post the php code for the controller and model that is being used for this page.

Comment: Hey. Sry. Of coarse. I have updated the text with code from my controller and model. But once again, I guess it is a configuration since it works on my other sever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server may not be supporting PHP `"short_open_tag"`, so the actual code is displayed in model.

Enable `"short_open_tag"` in php.ini or use `<?php ?>` tags in models.